# Configuring a filter for Devexpress ASPxGridView

Tags: filter, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a column named Status that display an image corresponding to states. And I have a filter on this column. How can I localize?

```
<dx:GridViewDataImageColumn Caption="Status" FieldName="Status" Width="100px" 
ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="9">
<Settings AllowSort="True" SortMode="Value" AllowHeaderFilter="True" ShowInFilterControl="True" />
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</dx:GridViewDataImageColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand your task correctly.  However, it seems that you need to use the gridView's [HeaderFilterFillItems](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_HeaderFilterFillItemstopic) event to accomplish your task.